# how to import variable from class correctly

Tags: python

I have the problem that in my app.py file in the class ChatApp inside a function a variable called index with an ID. I want to import this variable afterwards into my chat.py file.

```
index = 0


class ChatApp:
    global index
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_index()

    def create_index(self):
        global index
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO chats (content) VALUES(Null)")
        db_getid = pd.read_sql('select id from chats order by id desc limit 1', connection)
        index = db_getid["id"][0]
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

Since index has the value 0 at the beginning, it is also only imported. How do I get that the import only takes place as soon as index contains the ID?

Comment: You should store the index as a class variable `self.index´ and access it through the class instance you creare instead of making it a module global variable.

Comment: you mean under the "_ _init_ _" function? how do I get access to this variable then?

Comment: I posted an answer with example, it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The index should be a class instance variable, example:

```
class ChatApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_index()

    def create_index(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO chats (content) VALUES(Null)")
        db_getid = pd.read_sql('select id from chats order by id desc limit 1', connection)
        self.index = db_getid["id"][0]
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

... in other python file:

```
from app import ChatApp

app = ChatApp()
index = app.index
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But there is still another problem. The app.py with its "_ _init_ _" function hast one more declaration, that starts an tkinter interface. So when I use your method in my chat.py file. Every time the function that uses the index variable is called, another window of my interface will open.

Comment: You should not create a new instance of ChatApp (by calling `ChatApp()` every time you need the index.. just call it once and store a reference to the instance in the calling code (maybe in a class or global variable there). That code can then just reference `.index` in that instance whenever it needs to.

Comment: I call the .index In a function in chat.py one time but when I start my program, there appear 2 windows. So calling the .index function via app= ChatApp() index = app.index ensures that the entire ChatApp class is executed. Unfortunately, I don't understand why.

Comment: @kaan46: It's impossible to debug unseen code. If you have another question, post it separately and include the code.